# JSON Array vs Object / Datatables

Tags: php, json, datatables

According to http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp, a JSON 'array' is like this:

```
"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
    {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
]
```

According to the same source, this is a JSON 'object':

```
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}
```

I have developed an API for my app and this is the JSON response I am receiving:

```
{
    "status":"success",
    "message": [
        {
            "entry_id":"1",
            "entry_name":"12345678",
            "entry_body":"this is just the beginning update",
            "entry_date":"2016-05-01 08:25:51",
            "status":"active","created_timestamp":"2016-05-01 21:25:51",
            "updated_timestamp":null
        },

        {
            "entry_id":"2",
            "entry_name":"one one one",
            "entry_body":"this is just the beginning update 1",
            "entry_date":"2016-05-02 01:44:03",
            "status":"active",
            "created_timestamp":"2016-05-02 14:44:03",　　
            "updated_timestamp":null
        },
        {
            "entry_id":"3",
        　　　"entry_name":"two two two",
        　　　"entry_body":"this is just the beginning update 2",
        　　　"entry_date":"2016-05-02 01:44:13",
        　　　"status":"active",
        　　　"created_timestamp":"2016-05-02 14:44:13",
        　　　"updated_timestamp":null
        }
    ]
}
```

In datatables, I have made the following script but it is not reading the JSON file:

```
var table = $('#list_blogs_table').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
         "url": "/BlogApiV1/BlogApi/blogs",
        "dataSrc": "message",
    }
    "columnDefs":
    [
        {
```

My URL must be a GET method though (am I doing that correctly)?

Also, assume my JSON data is considered an ARRAY.  Is that correct?  I tell datatables that the data starts from 'message' by declaring `"dataSrc": "message",`.  Is that correct?

Comment: @user3264461 what you say is correct. have you looked in the Network tab on Chrome Dev Tools to make sure that that JSON is what you actually get on the frontend and that you don't have any other js errors on page?

Comment: @lolka_bolka "message" as a String is the correct argument for the "dataSrc" option

Comment: @edhurtig deleted my comment, I did not realized, that is a DataTable callback.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON includes multiple hidden illegal control chars, it seems to be escapes and invalid tabs. Even though your JSON would work as a literal defined locally, it will fail when passed over a network and JSONified on the client.

In the future, you can use **https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com** to see exactly what is wrong with the JSON. You can use **https://myjson.com** to validate too, since it is using `JSON.parse()`, not an algorithmic test like **http://jsonlint.com** which would falsy consider your JSON as valid.

So simply cleanup the JSON and it works :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/14lrs", 
    dataSrc: "message",
  },
  columnDefs: [
    { targets: 0, data: 'entry_id' },
    { targets: 1, data: 'entry_name' }
  ]
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/3wr2j2yx/**

Try grab the cleaned JSON from http://myjson.com/14lrs and use that as source instead.

> My URL must be a GET method though (am I doing that correctly)?

Yes!

> Also, assume my JSON data is considered an ARRAY. Is that correct? I
>   tell datatables that the data starts from 'message' by declaring
>   "dataSrc": "message",. Is that correct?

Yes!

Comment: Thank you for providing so much detail.  Indeed, I had placed "columnDefs" in the wrong place.  Sorted that now.  I now get the following error:  DataTables warning: table id=list_blogs_table - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0. I changed the url to http://myjson.com/14lrs and get the same error.  Went through my jquery and html and all looks correct too.

Comment: BTW, I also noticed "update_timestamp" was set to "" is your example and NULL in mine.  I changed all the entries to actual date/times but no luck.

Comment: BTW, I rane my json through the links you provided and it says my JSON is valid.  How did you find the escapes and invalid tabs?  Also, why would it work locally?  Actually, both the API server and client are local and no FQD are being used (i think).

Comment: @user3264461, you should NOT use http://myjson.com/14lrs as source, this link is for viewing the data formatted for human reading, you need to use https://api.myjson.com/bins/14lrs if you want to use it as source for an AJAX request. My only idea with mentioning http://myjson.com/14lrs was that you could **see** what edtings I have made, and you could copy paste the content into a test file.

Comment: @user3264461, I did set the `update_timestamp` to `""` because it annoyed me, there should be no problem at all using `null` with dataTables, it is just bad JSON.

Comment: @user3264461 - It would work "locally" because if you have the JSON as a literal in javascript, then hidden control chars is filtered out by the browser.  If you pass it over a network, however, then  `\t` or any special character need to be in **unicode**, otherwise the request fails (if valid JSON is expected).

Answer (score 0):

To see what your json turns into do var_dump or var_export.

Like lets assume your response is stored in the variable `$response`

```
$object = json_decode($response);
var_export($object);
var_dump($object);
```

we get the following:

```
 stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'status' => 'success',
   'message' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'entry_id' => '1',
       'entry_name' => '12345678',
       'entry_body' => 'this is just the beginning update',
       'entry_date' => '2016-05-01 08:25:51',
       'status' => 'active',
       'created_timestamp' => '2016-05-01 21:25:51',
       'updated_timestamp' => NULL,
    )),
    1 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'entry_id' => '2',
       'entry_name' => 'one one one',
       'entry_body' => 'this is just the beginning update 1',
       'entry_date' => '2016-05-02 01:44:03',
       'status' => 'active',
       'created_timestamp' => '2016-05-02 14:44:03',
       'updated_timestamp' => NULL,
    )),
    2 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'entry_id' => '3',
       'entry_name' => 'two two two',
       'entry_body' => 'this is just the beginning update 2',
       'entry_date' => '2016-05-02 01:44:13',
       'status' => 'active',
       'created_timestamp' => '2016-05-02 14:44:13',
       'updated_timestamp' => NULL,
    )),
  ),
))


object(stdClass)#511 (2) {
  ["status"]=>
  string(7) "success"
  ["message"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#512 (7) {
      ["entry_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["entry_name"]=>
      string(8) "12345678"
      ["entry_body"]=>
      string(33) "this is just the beginning update"
      ["entry_date"]=>
      string(19) "2016-05-01 08:25:51"
      ["status"]=>
      string(6) "active"
      ["created_timestamp"]=>
      string(19) "2016-05-01 21:25:51"
      ["updated_timestamp"]=>
      NULL
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#513 (7) {
      ["entry_id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["entry_name"]=>
      string(11) "one one one"
      ["entry_body"]=>
      string(35) "this is just the beginning update 1"
      ["entry_date"]=>
      string(19) "2016-05-02 01:44:03"
      ["status"]=>
      string(6) "active"
      ["created_timestamp"]=>
      string(19) "2016-05-02 14:44:03"
      ["updated_timestamp"]=>
      NULL
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#514 (7) {
      ["entry_id"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["entry_name"]=>
      string(11) "two two two"
      ["entry_body"]=>
      string(35) "this is just the beginning update 2"
      ["entry_date"]=>
      string(19) "2016-05-02 01:44:13"
      ["status"]=>
      string(6) "active"
      ["created_timestamp"]=>
      string(19) "2016-05-02 14:44:13"
      ["updated_timestamp"]=>
      NULL
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, your structure resolves to an object, that's an associative array that contains an array that contains an object that's an assocaitve array;

This means you can't access as associative array.

so $object['message'] wont work, but $object->message will work :-)

```
var_dump($var->message[0])
```

resolves to

```
object(stdClass)#512 (7) {
  ["entry_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["entry_name"]=>
  string(8) "12345678"
  ["entry_body"]=>
  string(33) "this is just the beginning update"
  ["entry_date"]=>
  string(19) "2016-05-01 08:25:51"
  ["status"]=>
  string(6) "active"
  ["created_timestamp"]=>
  string(19) "2016-05-01 21:25:51"
  ["updated_timestamp"]=>
  NULL
}
```

you can access it like this :-)

```
$myobj = $var->message[0]

echo $myobj->status == 'active'
```

in javascript it'd be,

```
var obj = JSON.parse(message);
myobj = obj.message[0];
echo myobj.status == 'active';
```

If you overwrite jquery's ajax call you can see that the following call is sent out to your server(see the code by my snippet for how to see this)

As you can see your arguments get sent as extra arguments to the server.

[Object]
0: Object
   cache: false
   data: Object
   dataSrc: "message"
   dataType: "json"
   error : (b,c)
   success: (b)
   type : "GET"
   url : "/BlogApiV1/BlogApi/blogs"

And your ajax response should look like this:

```
{
    "status":"success",
    "data": [
        [
            "1",
            "12345678",
            "this is just the beginning update",
            "2016-05-01 08:25:51",
            "active",
            "2016-05-01 21:25:51",
            null
        ],
        [
            "2",
            "one one one",
            "this is just the beginning update 1",
            "2016-05-02 01:44:03",
            "active",
            "2016-05-02 14:44:03",
            null
          ],
         [
            "3",
            "two two two",
            "this is just the beginning update 2",
            "2016-05-02 01:44:13",
            "active",
            "2016-05-02 14:44:13",
            null
        ]
    ]
}
```

Please refer to the datatables examples pages and check out the source tabs at the bottom :-) they give examples how they expect stuff to be formatted :-)

Comment: Although this is a great explanation of interacting with JSON in PHP, it seems like the question is largely directed at issues with DataTables (JS).  But again, very useful answer, and @user3264461 might find me wrong in this case : )

Comment: Well, it was tagged php, so i assumed a php explanation could be valid too to help him understand the structure. I'll add a javascript explanation too

Comment: Cool just thought I'd point it out : ).  I'll bet the JS explanation will also be very helpful!

Comment: @michael-dibbets This is incredible feedback!!!  More than I expected.  Don't quite understand this comment, "As you can see your arguments get sent as extra arguments to the server" but still reading more....

Comment: My JSON seems to be valid under 
http://jsfiddle.net/3wr2j2yx/ 

@davidconrad seems to have got it working... although I am still having trouble.

Comment: FYI, I am using Phil Sturgeon's rest server to generate the JSON, too (https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver).

Answer (score 0):

Have sorted out the problems.  The solution was fixing the JSON output per @Michael-Dibbets' great breakdown.  I am actually using Phil Sturgeon's REST server to help create the API. The default appears to be JSON output, however, again, as Michael-Dibbets has pointed out, the JSON is not valid.  The REST server permits formats, including xml, csv, etc, etc.  Rather than relying on the default, I specifically stated the format in the URL like  /BlogApiV1/BlogApi/blogs/format/json and this fixed everything. Thank you for everyone's comments and certainly learnt a lot from the error.